# Jenkins job failing with ClassNotFoundException: Classloading from system classloader disabled

Tags: macos, jenkins

I've encountered a strange problem with Jenkins when running a job on MacOSX. The same job passes sometimes and fails other times without any changes made in the job config which is weird. I've included the exception stack trace below. If anybody here in SO has encountered such issues, I would love to hear about how you solved it.

For reference: I've looked at the issue post in Jenkins [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10238) but it seems it is what is causing the problem for me.

```
FATAL: Remote call on Mac Mini tester failed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Classloading from system classloader disabled
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:816)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:849)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3280.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:895)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.CallableDecorator.call(CallableDecorator.java:19)
    at hudson.remoting.CallableDecoratorList$1.call(CallableDecoratorList.java:21)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to channel(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:260)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.fetch3(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:187)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection.<clinit>(ProcessTree.java:699)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1004)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:995)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused: java.lang.LinkageError
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixReflection.<clinit>(ProcessTree.java:710)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:647)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:668)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:589)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:1004)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:995)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    at ......remote call to Mac Mini tester(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on Mac Mini tester failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:838)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:992)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:496)
    at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild$MultiJobRunnerImpl.run(MultiJobBuild.java:136)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild.run(MultiJobBuild.java:73)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
```

Comment: Why don't you try to restart Jenkins?That might help.

Comment: Restarting Jenkins did not help

Comment: Do you have found a solution? Since a week we have the same problem.